# HTTP Post triggering error when HTTP get working fine

Tags: c#, angular, asmx, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I am facing an issue with HTTP post method to save some details into DB via ASMX webservice.

Here is my save method

```
  createRequest(data:myRequest):Observable<any>{
    //let param:string=JSON.stringify({name:'san'});
    /* const httpoptions={headers:new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset= utf-8'}),withCredentials:true} */
      return this.client.post('http://localhost:51071/webservice1.asmx/saveCrData',
      JSON.stringify({name:'san'}),
        { headers:new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'}),
          withCredentials:true, responseType: 'json'  }
      );
  }
```

Here is my function defenition in asmx

```
[WebMethod]
public int saveCrData(string name)
{
          return 1;
}
```

But its triggering some CORS error. The CORS error I really believe its not really a CORS issue since I have another get method which is working fine without any trouble. I have had similar CORS issue there when I specify **Content-Type as application/json** . But in this POST method I have not idea whats causing the issue.

Here is my get method

```
  getCrformLocations() {
    //    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set({Content-Type : 'text/plan; charset=utf-8'})
    return this.client.get('http://localhost:51071/webservice1.asmx/getLocation', {
      withCredentials: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    }); //, headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset= utf-8'})
    //.subscribe( (data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
  }
```

service definition

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,ResponseFormat =ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void getLocation() {
//mycode
}
```

Error
[image]

Please help me to solve this block

Comment: Does the start.cs file have CORS allowing that port?

Comment: What I did for CORS is at server side to allow this angular url.. Havent done anything at client side